How can I find out if this 1st order quasi-linear pde has *no solution*
Consider $$R(x) = \begin{cases} 0, & x < 0, \\ x, & 0 \le x \le 1, \\ 1, & x > 1 \end{cases}$$ and the first order quasi-linear PDE
$$
\begin{cases}
\partial_t g(t, s) = 2 s - 2 R(g(t, s)), & t > 0, 0 < s < 1, \\
g(0, s) = 0, & 0 < s < 1.
\end{cases}
$$

I think there is no solution, but how can I prove it?

WolframAlpha gives the following solution
$$
g(t, s) = \left( x \mapsto \int_{1}^{x} \frac{1}{s - R(\xi)} \, \text{d}\xi\right)^{-1}\left(c_1(s) + 2 t\right).
$$
Plugging in $t = 0$ yields
$$
\int_{1}^{g(0, s)} \frac{1}{s - R(\xi)} \; \text{d}\xi
= c_1(s).
$$
However, the integral on the left hand side is
$$
\int_{1}^{0} \frac{1}{s - \xi} \; \text{d}\xi,
$$
which is indeterminate due to the singularity at $\xi = s$.

The answer from Toby Saunders-A'Court begins with an assumption. The assumption is found valid at the end. So his answer is correct and this is by far the simplest way to solve the problem.
More tiresome : How to proceed without assomption ?
$$
\begin{cases}
\partial_t g(t, s) = 2 s - 2 R(g(t, s)), & t > 0, 0 < s < 1, \\
g(0, s) = 0, & 0 < s < 1.
\end{cases}
$$
$R(g)$ might have three forms respectively $R(g)=0$ , $R(g)=g$, $R(g)=1$. This means that one can consider three distinct PDEs each one valid in a different domain.
We solve the three PDE (which in fact are ODEs) without considering the limits of the respective domains.
First case $R(g)=0$ :
$\partial_t g(t, s) = 2 s\quad\implies\quad g(t,s)=2st+C_1(s)$
With initial condition $g(0,s)=0\quad\implies\quad C_1(s)=0$ :
$$g(t,s)=2st$$
Second case $R(g)=g$ :
$\partial_t g(t, s) = 2 s - 2 g \quad\implies\quad g(t,s)=s+e^{-2t}C_2(s)$
With initial condition $g(0,s)=0\quad\implies\quad C_2(s)=-s$ :
$$g(t,s)=s(1-e^{-2t})$$
Third case $R(g)=1$ :
$\partial_t g(t, s) = 2 s-2\quad\implies\quad g(t,s)=2st-2t+C_3(s)$
With initial condition $g(0,s)=0\quad\implies\quad C_3(s)=0$ :
$$g(t,s)=2t(s-1)$$
Then considering the definition of $R(g(t,s))$ on the domain $t>0$ and $0<s<1$ :
$$R(g) = \begin{cases} 0, & g < 0, \\ g, & 0 \le g \le 1, \\ 1, & g > 1 \end{cases}$$
First case $g(t,s)=2st\quad\implies\quad g>0 \quad\implies\quad $ Thus $g<0$ doesn't exist on the domain $t>0$ and $0<s<1$.
Second case $g(t,s)=s(1-e^{-2t})\quad\implies\quad 0\leq g<1 \quad\implies\quad $ is compatible with the definition of $R(g)$.
Third case $g(t,s)=2t(s-1)\quad\implies\quad g<0 \quad\implies\quad $ Thus $g>1$ doesn't exist on the domain $t>0$ and $0<s<1$.
Thus the unique result is :
$$\boxed{g(t,s)=s(1-e^{-2t})}$$

Thank you for your answer! Why can we solve the three ODEs corresponding to the three cases, why can't it be the case that for some $t>0$ $g(t,\cdot)$ is in one case and for other $t$ it is in a different case? Ultimately, I want to solve my ODE for more general $R$ and different initial conditions.

<< why can't it be the case that for some t>0 g(t,⋅) is in one case and for other t it is in a different case? >> :  It can bee for different wording of the problem. For example if two cases are valid the two corresponding equations $g(t,s)$ are valid each one in a different domain. We would have to determine what is the boundary between the two domains and if crossing the boundary (i.e. going from a first function $g(t,s)$ to a second function $g(t,s)$ is continuous or discontinuous.

Possibly in such a situation the two different $g(t,s)$ could be replaced by a common equation $g(t,s)$ involving Heaviside's function.

Ok, how would that look like? Because if e.g. we pose $g(0, s) \equiv q$ for some $q \in \mathbb R \setminus { 0 }$ your reasoning doesn't work anymore, because then the three cases yield, $g(t, s) = 2 s t + q$, $g(t, s) = (1 - e^{-2 t}) s + e^{-2 t} q$ and a contradiction, respectively. For $q \ge 1$, I used the solution from WolframAlpha I outlined in my question, which yields $$g_t(s) = \begin{cases} s + (1 - s) \exp\left( \frac{q - 1}{1 - s} - 2 t\right),    & \text{if } s \le 1 - \frac{q - 1}{2 t}, \  (s - 1) \left( 2 t - \frac{q - 1}{1 - s}\right) + 1, & \text{else.}  \end{cases}.$$

The three equations are : first $g(t,s)=2st+q$ , second $g(t,s)=s(1-e^{-2t})+qe^{-2t}$, third $g(t,s)=2t(s-1)+q$. For each one of these three cases they are several sub-cases depending from $q$. One have to study when $g<0$, when $0\leq g \leq 1$ and when $g>1$. For a given value of $q$ this can be visulised on a graph with $t$ on horizontal axis and $s$ on vertical axis and drawing the curves boarding the domains. Then in each domain one can determine which equation is valid or not. This is a big work and this is a too wide question to be discussed without ambiguity in comments.
